# 2-point spin correlator in CFT

Tags: quantum-spin, conformal-field-theory, correlation-functions

I'm currently studying CFT and trying to write correlation functions, mas having trouble when it comes to operators with spin.
The problem that I have is to write the 2 point correlation function of spin 2 operators in the embedding formalism. The answer that I have is:

$$\left<O_1^{A_1A_2}(X_1)O_2^{B_1B_2}(X_2)\right>=a\,\delta^{A_1A_2}\delta^{B_1B_2}(X_1 \cdot X_2)^2 + b\, \left(\delta^{A_1B_1}\delta^{A_2B_2} + \delta^{A_1B_2}\delta^{A_2B_1}\right) (X_1 \cdot X_2)^2 + c\,X_1^{B_1}X_1^{B_2}X_2^{A_1}X_2^{A_2} + \cdots$$

My question is: where do these terms come from? Every paper that I've read assumes this as a pretty obvious thing, but I just can't understand. What am I missing?

Comment: Please add a reference that states your mystery correlator

Comment: If you saturate the indices with $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ polarizations, the 2pt function can be written as $H_{12}^2$ as defined in https://arxiv.org/abs/1107.3554

Comment: @ɪdɪətstrəʊlə it's just something I wrote from the board in class, sorry

Comment: @ConnorBehan i'm going to check it, thank you